# Return Kth to Last: Incorrect output

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a simple algorithm of trying to find the kth to last element from the Linearly Linked Lists
However, at my solution, it's not outputting the correct number that I expect.

I know how to solve the problem, but I'm wondering why doesn't the head recursion work the way I intended. And I would appreciate it if I receive another pair of eyes.

Wrapper function

```
public int findKthToLast(int kth){
        //If zero items in the list
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("List is empty");
            return 0;
        }
        //If 1 item in the list
        if(head.getNext() == null){
            System.out.println("Only 1 item in the list which is: " + head.getData());
            return 0;
        }
        //Allocating an array of size 1. This will help me keep track on what kth element when I go back from the recursion
        int[] array = new int[1];
        array[0] = -1;

        //the '1' below represents the length. it will increment as you see in the recursive solution
        return findKthToLast(head,kth,1,array);
    }
```

Recursion

```
public int findKthToLast(Node head,int kth,int length, int [] array){
        //if final item in the list
        if(head.getNext() == null){
            //if kth element is greater then total length just return 0
            if(kth >= length){
                return 0;
            }
            //kth = 0 means output the final item in the list. returns head.data
            if(kth == 0){
                return head.getData();
            }
            //when I backtrack from the stack I need to know if the kth to final element is equal to length. That's where the array comes from
            array[0] = length - kth;
            return 0;
        }
        int element;
        element = findKthToLast(head.getNext(),kth,++length,array);
         
        //if equal then I'm done. return the head.data
        if(length == array[0]){
            return head.getData();
        }
        return element;

    }
```

the Problem:

In the list: 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1. If kth = 1 (I want the item before last so in this case the value "2") the output should be "2". However, in my current code, I'm receiving 1 number higher so the value "4"

I don't want the correct code. I know if I changed my base case from

```
if(head.getNext() == null)
to 
if(head == null)
```

then my code works completely fine. What I want is why doesn't my current solution work. Am I visualizing the call stack incorrectly? Thank you

Comment: Done any debugging yet? What were your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably outsmarted yourself because you have a really perverse way of computing the length of your list on each recursion call. Instead of just adding one to the current length, you modified the length variable so that you correctly pass in the increased length into the next recursive call... however you then use that incremented length when your function pops out, causing you to miscount.

Let's step through the example below:

```
8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
findKthToLast(8, 1, 1, [-1])
|
|-> 8.next is NOT null
    |
    | element = findKthToLast(4, 1, ++1, [-1])
      |
      | -> 4.next is NOT null
           |
           | element = findKthToLast(2, 1, ++2, [-1])
             |
             | -> 2.next is NOT null
                  |
                  | element = findKthToLast(1, 1, ++3, [-1])
                    |
                    | -> 1.next IS null
                         | kth is NOT 0
                         | => array[0] <- 4 - 1 = 3 (correct)
                         | return 0
                    | element = 0
                    | length is 4 != 3 because of prefix increment (length should be 3 but you incremented before calling the function)
                    | return 0
             | element = 0
             | length is 3 == 3 because of prefix increment, so return current node
             | return 2 (not correct but this is what you told the code to do)
      | element = 2
      | length is 2 != array[0] 
      | return 2
| return 2
```

Personally, I'd go for a two pointer slow/fast approach, but if you *must* use recursion, then I would make it easier on myself and maintain a length counter that is incremented in the back (the last element returns 0, then on subsequent calls return `element + 1`) and store the correct value in the array instead.